# Get month and year when browsing the Calandar WebForm ASPX control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, calendar

I would like to ask you for help, I need to get the month and year of the calendar control at the time that the user changes the month or year directly in the control.

Is it possible?

I need to change the color of the days that contain data in the SQL database, the code is OK but it is necessary to pass the Month and Year parameters to a stored procedure at the moment when the user changes the month or year in the Calendar control.

I am grateful in advance for your help.

I can only get the month and year from the current date when the control is loaded more when I change to another month or year, I cannot get this information.

Can you help me?

```
MesCalendar.Text = CalendarioPrincipal.VisibleDate.Month
AnoCalendar.Text = CalendarioPrincipal.VisibleDate.Year
```